# I can't enable my module with di.xml in magento

Tags: magento2, di.xml

My di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Mageplaza\BannerSlider\Block\Slider" type="Movistar\BannerSlider\Block\Slider\Slider"/>
</config>
```

Mi module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Movistar_BannerSlider" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Mageplaza_BannerSlider"/>
        </sequence>    
    </module>
</config>
```

Mi layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="banner.slider">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Movistar_BannerSlider::bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml</argument>            
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I cannot disable the vendor module, Mageplaza and use the custom module that I create myself in magento 2. Which when using template hints in the front of my store the banner and slider point me to the vendor directory and not to my own.

Comment: Do you have your module enabled and cleared the `config` cache after you've placed your changes in di.xml?

Comment: It still doesn't work for me!

Comment: Take a look at env.php, at the `modules` section, maybe you have it enabled there, so every time you run `setup:upgrade` it will enable itself, regardless of what you have inside config.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `module.xml` configuration file includes the `<sequence>` tag in order to enforce the loading of your module after the 'Mageplaza_BannerSlider' module.

Comment: Hello, first of all, please excuse my delay in answering and that I cannot rate your question as I have a low reputation. On the other hand I have been with this problem since then, very stressful magento 2. My problem lies in the banner of the store, it is working with the bannerSlider/mageplaza a third-party module. I try to override the phtml file of the third party module to use my custom module and the store is not taking the module or the phtml file from me. I have been for days without knowing what the problem is since I followed all the corresponding steps to enable my module.thanks

Comment: I have also done tests. I add a paragraph in the third-party module and the page renders it for me now I add logic or some test tag in my custom phtml file and it does not show me. There is no case !!

Comment: hi there! sorry to hear you still struggle with this. could you maybe try to overwrite this in your custom theme?

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean look, copied and pasted the third party phtml template in my custom module of the design / frontend - "Mageplaza_BannerSlider" and it worked directly, just add the phtml file I mean, no need to add di.xml or module.xml. As I previously told you, I was extending a third-party module in code / Movistar / BannerSlider adding the folders Block, etc, Setup (I have to do an UpgradeSchema) and view, pasting said custom template there and it didn't work. I have done it.

Comment: Right now I am with another problem, I would like to know how I can show the banners of the store according to the category, that is, if the category in which I am is "business" to show the banners corresponding to businesses. I would not be dating, if you can help me I will love you